# How to not disturb parent div during drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a js that constructs field layouts for me. I am trying to drag and drop a field in between the divs.

The original layout will be like

```
<div class="rowOfFields">
   <div class="field"> field_1 </div> <div class="field"> field_2 </div>
</div>
<div class="rowOfFields">
    <div class=field> field_3 </div> <div class=field>field_4</div> 
</div>
```

Which will be displayed like

```
Field_1 : [__________]    Field_2 : [___________]
Field_3 : [__________]    Field_4 : [___________]     //base structure
Field_5 : [__________]    Field_6 : [___________]
```

Now I am trying to drag a div from another container and place it in between Field 2 and Field 4. But what happens is, Field 3 and Field 4 goes down like,

```
Field_1 : [__________]    Field_2 : [___________]

                          Drag_FLD: [-----------]   //Not preferred

Field_3 : [__________]    Field_4 : [___________]

Field_5 : [__________]    Field_6 : [___________]
```

I want the Field_3 to stay in left of Drag_FLD so that only Field_4 goes down like.

```
Field_1 : [__________]    Field_2 : [___________]

Field_3 : [__________]    Drag_FLD: [-----------]    //Preferred

Field_5 : [__________]    Field_4 : [___________]

                          Field_6 : [__________]
```

I amm using draggable to drag the Drag_FLD element and connecting it to sortable of div's with class:"field". I am trying to achieve ul li sortable using div structure.

If what I am trying to tell is hard to understand, kindly forgive the explanation as I am new to this.

PS : I can only scope the field in rows and not in columns as the layout is placed in DOM by a thirdparty DOM Constructor

Comment: Try giving float to `rowFields`

Comment: I tried them, but does not work